# How can I highlight a date area in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, graph, highlight

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      new Dygraph(
              document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
              function() {
                var zp = function(x) { if (x < 10) return "0"+x; else return x; };
                var r = "date,parabola,line,another line,sine wave\n";
                for (var i=1; i<=31; i++) {
                r += "200610" + zp(i);
                r += "," + 10*(i*(31-i));
                r += "," + 10*(8*i);
                r += "," + 10*(250 - 8*i);
                r += "," + 10*(125 + 125 * Math.sin(0.3*i));
                r += "\n";
                }
                return r;
              },
              {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                'parabola': {
                  strokeWidth: 0.0,
                  drawPoints: true,
                  pointSize: 4,
                  highlightCircleSize: 6
                },
                'line': {
                  strokeWidth: 1.0,
                  drawPoints: true,
                  pointSize: 1.5
                },
                'sine wave': {
                  strokeWidth: 3,
                  highlightCircleSize: 10
                }
              }
          );
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    "Date,Close Price\n" +
"2015-09-17,5.20\n" + 
"2015-09-16,5.31\n" + 
"2015-09-15,5.40\n" + 
"2015-09-14,5.20\n" + 
"2015-09-11,5.17\n" + 
"2015-09-10,5.20\n" + 
"2015-09-09,5.09\n" + 
"2015-09-08,5.05\n" + 
"2015-09-07,4.90\n" + 
"2015-09-04,4.74\n" + 
"2015-09-03,4.68\n" + 
"2015-09-02,4.24\n" + 
"2015-09-01,4.20\n" + 
"2015-08-31,4.06\n" + 
"2015-08-28,4.19\n" + 
"2015-08-27,4.08\n" + 
"2015-08-26,4.20\n" + 
"2015-08-25,4.04\n" + 
"2015-08-24,3.53\n" + 
"2015-08-21,4.30\n" + 
"2015-08-20,4.45\n" + 
"2015-08-19,4.58\n" + 
"2015-08-18,4.54\n" + 
"2015-08-17,4.63\n" + 
"2015-08-14,4.49\n" + 
"2015-08-13,4.56\n" + 
"2015-08-12,4.69\n" + 
"2015-08-11,4.80\n" + 
"2015-08-10,4.65\n" + 
"2015-08-07,4.40\n" + 
"2015-08-06,4.24\n" + 
"2015-08-05,3.98\n" + 
"2015-08-04,3.84\n" + 
"2015-08-03,3.66\n" + 
"2015-07-31,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-30,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-29,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-28,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-27,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-24,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-23,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-22,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-21,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-20,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-17,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-16,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-15,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-14,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-13,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-10,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-09,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-08,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-07,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-06,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-03,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-02,4.71\n" + 
"2015-07-01,4.71\n" + 
"2015-06-30,4.71\n" + 
"2015-06-29,4.71\n" + 
"2015-06-26,4.71\n" + 
"2015-06-25,4.45\n" + 
"2015-06-24,4.43\n" + 
"2015-06-23,4.41\n" + 
"2015-06-22,4.14\n" + 
"2015-06-19,3.84\n" + 
"2015-06-18,3.65\n" + 
"2015-06-17,3.63\n" + 
"2015-06-16,4.23\n" + 
"2015-06-15,4.49\n" + 
"2015-06-12,4.74\n" + 
"2015-06-11,5.04\n" + 
"2015-06-10,4.75\n" + 
"2015-06-09,4.75\n" + 
"2015-06-08,4.61\n" + 
"2015-06-05,4.69\n" + 
"2015-06-04,4.91\n" + 
"2015-06-03,4.94\n" + 
"2015-06-02,4.68\n" + 
"2015-06-01,4.56\n" + 
"2015-05-29,4.56\n" + 
"2015-05-28,4.96\n" + 
"2015-05-27,5.29\n" + 
"2015-05-26,4.75\n" + 
"2015-05-25,4.88\n" + 
"2015-05-22,5.06\n" + 
"2015-05-21,5.18\n" + 
"2015-05-20,5.07\n" + 
"2015-05-19,5.28\n" + 
"2015-05-18,5.26\n" + 
"2015-05-15,4.95\n" + 
"2015-05-14,5.00\n" + 
"2015-05-13,5.18\n" + 
"2015-05-12,5.49\n" + 
"2015-05-11,5.50\n" + 
"2015-05-08,5.74\n" + 
"2015-05-07,5.84\n" + 
"2015-05-06,5.60\n" + 
"2015-05-05,5.28\n" + 
"2015-05-04,5.80\n" + 
"2015-05-01,5.99\n" + 
"2015-04-30,5.99\n" + 
"2015-04-29,5.46\n" + 
"2015-04-28,5.58\n" + 
"2015-04-27,5.45\n" + 
"2015-04-24,4.97\n" + 
"2015-04-23,4.87\n" + 
"2015-04-22,4.57\n" + 
"2015-04-21,4.30\n" + 
"2015-04-20,4.85\n" + 
"2015-04-17,4.86\n" + 
"2015-04-16,5.09\n" + 
"2015-04-15,4.80\n" + 
"2015-04-14,5.00\n" + 
"2015-04-13,5.45\n" + 
"2015-04-10,5.45\n" + 
"2015-04-09,5.45\n" + 
"2015-04-08,5.38\n" + 
"2015-04-07,5.42\n" + 
"2015-04-06,5.50\n" + 
"2015-04-03,5.50\n" + 
"2015-04-02,5.50\n" + 
"2015-04-01,5.49\n" + 
"2015-03-31,5.70\n" + 
"2015-03-30,5.80\n" + 
"2015-03-27,5.68\n" + 
"2015-03-26,5.40\n" + 
"2015-03-25,5.83\n" + 
"2015-03-24,5.83\n" + 
"2015-03-23,5.30\n" + 
"2015-03-20,5.01\n" + 
"2015-03-19,4.84\n" + 
"2015-03-18,4.90\n" + 
"2015-03-17,5.13\n" + 
"2015-03-16,4.91\n" + 
"2015-03-13,5.18\n" + 
"2015-03-12,5.53\n" + 
"2015-03-11,5.58\n" + 
"2015-03-10,5.70\n" + 
"2015-03-09,5.60\n" + 
"2015-03-06,6.15\n" + 
"2015-03-05,6.19\n" + 
"2015-03-04,6.40\n" + 
"2015-03-03,6.32\n" + 
"2015-03-02,6.51\n" + 
"2015-02-27,7.00\n" + 
"2015-02-26,7.30\n" + 
"2015-02-25,7.50\n" + 
"2015-02-24,6.88\n" + 
"2015-02-23,6.05\n" + 
"2015-02-20,6.05\n" + 
"2015-02-19,6.09\n" + 
"2015-02-18,5.90\n" + 
"2015-02-17,5.98\n" + 
"2015-02-16,6.00\n" + 
"2015-02-13,6.20\n" + 
"2015-02-12,5.54\n" + 
"2015-02-11,5.25\n" + 
"2015-02-10,5.64\n" + 
"2015-02-09,5.18\n" + 
"2015-02-06,5.15\n" + 
"2015-02-05,5.27\n" + 
"2015-02-04,5.50\n" + 
"2015-02-03,5.69\n" + 
"2015-02-02,5.12\n" + 
"2015-01-30,4.80\n" + 
"2015-01-29,4.78\n" + 
"2015-01-28,4.45\n" + 
"2015-01-27,5.17\n" + 
"2015-01-26,5.82\n" + 
"2015-01-23,5.63\n" + 
"2015-01-22,5.16\n" + 
"2015-01-21,4.94\n" + 
"2015-01-20,5.18\n" + 
"2015-01-19,5.20\n" + 
"2015-01-16,4.77\n" + 
"2015-01-15,4.90\n" + 
"2015-01-14,5.03\n" + 
"2015-01-13,5.31\n" + 
"2015-01-12,5.20\n" + 
"2015-01-09,4.93\n" + 
"2015-01-08,4.76\n" + 
"2015-01-07,4.97\n" + 
"2015-01-06,5.07\n" + 
"2015-01-05,5.07\n" + 
"2015-01-02,5.55\n" + 
"2015-01-01,5.40\n" + 
"2015-10-28,10"
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This shows a graph. Now I want to highlight a date-area, like in the tutorial example here: http://dygraphs.com/...hlighted-region

My problem is, that I can't figure out how I can use the date. E.g. `2015-01-01` to `2015-10-28` as highlight_start/highlight_end.

How can I highlight a day-range `2015-01-01` to `2015-10-28` in my example?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI your example link is broken but here is the real one http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-region

Comment: I updated my answer once again. It should be what you are looking for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question the first go around. It should now graph your CSV data and then highlight those date ranges specified. (You will notice the whole graph is yellow - this is because the highlight_start and highlight_end are larger than your data set).

```
var csvData = function() {
    return "Date,Close Price\n" +
        "2015-09-17,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-16,5.31\n" + 
        "2015-09-15,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-09-14,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-11,5.17\n" + 
        "2015-09-10,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-09,5.09\n" + 
        "2015-09-08,5.05\n" + 
        "2015-09-07,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-09-04,4.74\n" + 
        "2015-09-03,4.68\n" + 
        "2015-09-02,4.24\n" + 
        "2015-09-01,4.20\n" + 
        "2015-08-31,4.06\n" + 
        "2015-08-28,4.19\n" + 
        "2015-08-27,4.08\n" + 
        "2015-08-26,4.20\n" + 
        "2015-08-25,4.04\n" + 
        "2015-08-24,3.53\n" + 
        "2015-08-21,4.30\n" + 
        "2015-08-20,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-08-19,4.58\n" + 
        "2015-08-18,4.54\n" + 
        "2015-08-17,4.63\n" + 
        "2015-08-14,4.49\n" + 
        "2015-08-13,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-08-12,4.69\n" + 
        "2015-08-11,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-08-10,4.65\n" + 
        "2015-08-07,4.40\n" + 
        "2015-08-06,4.24\n" + 
        "2015-08-05,3.98\n" + 
        "2015-08-04,3.84\n" + 
        "2015-08-03,3.66\n" + 
        "2015-07-31,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-30,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-29,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-28,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-27,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-24,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-23,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-22,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-21,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-20,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-17,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-16,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-15,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-14,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-13,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-10,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-09,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-08,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-07,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-06,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-03,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-02,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-01,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-30,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-29,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-26,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-25,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-06-24,4.43\n" + 
        "2015-06-23,4.41\n" + 
        "2015-06-22,4.14\n" + 
        "2015-06-19,3.84\n" + 
        "2015-06-18,3.65\n" + 
        "2015-06-17,3.63\n" + 
        "2015-06-16,4.23\n" + 
        "2015-06-15,4.49\n" + 
        "2015-06-12,4.74\n" + 
        "2015-06-11,5.04\n" + 
        "2015-06-10,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-06-09,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-06-08,4.61\n" + 
        "2015-06-05,4.69\n" + 
        "2015-06-04,4.91\n" + 
        "2015-06-03,4.94\n" + 
        "2015-06-02,4.68\n" + 
        "2015-06-01,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-05-29,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-05-28,4.96\n" + 
        "2015-05-27,5.29\n" + 
        "2015-05-26,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-05-25,4.88\n" + 
        "2015-05-22,5.06\n" + 
        "2015-05-21,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-05-20,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-05-19,5.28\n" + 
        "2015-05-18,5.26\n" + 
        "2015-05-15,4.95\n" + 
        "2015-05-14,5.00\n" + 
        "2015-05-13,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-05-12,5.49\n" + 
        "2015-05-11,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-05-08,5.74\n" + 
        "2015-05-07,5.84\n" + 
        "2015-05-06,5.60\n" + 
        "2015-05-05,5.28\n" + 
        "2015-05-04,5.80\n" + 
        "2015-05-01,5.99\n" + 
        "2015-04-30,5.99\n" + 
        "2015-04-29,5.46\n" + 
        "2015-04-28,5.58\n" + 
        "2015-04-27,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-24,4.97\n" + 
        "2015-04-23,4.87\n" + 
        "2015-04-22,4.57\n" + 
        "2015-04-21,4.30\n" + 
        "2015-04-20,4.85\n" + 
        "2015-04-17,4.86\n" + 
        "2015-04-16,5.09\n" + 
        "2015-04-15,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-04-14,5.00\n" + 
        "2015-04-13,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-10,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-09,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-08,5.38\n" + 
        "2015-04-07,5.42\n" + 
        "2015-04-06,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-03,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-02,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-01,5.49\n" + 
        "2015-03-31,5.70\n" + 
        "2015-03-30,5.80\n" + 
        "2015-03-27,5.68\n" + 
        "2015-03-26,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-03-25,5.83\n" + 
        "2015-03-24,5.83\n" + 
        "2015-03-23,5.30\n" + 
        "2015-03-20,5.01\n" + 
        "2015-03-19,4.84\n" + 
        "2015-03-18,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-03-17,5.13\n" + 
        "2015-03-16,4.91\n" + 
        "2015-03-13,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-03-12,5.53\n" + 
        "2015-03-11,5.58\n" + 
        "2015-03-10,5.70\n" + 
        "2015-03-09,5.60\n" + 
        "2015-03-06,6.15\n" + 
        "2015-03-05,6.19\n" + 
        "2015-03-04,6.40\n" + 
        "2015-03-03,6.32\n" + 
        "2015-03-02,6.51\n" + 
        "2015-02-27,7.00\n" + 
        "2015-02-26,7.30\n" + 
        "2015-02-25,7.50\n" + 
        "2015-02-24,6.88\n" + 
        "2015-02-23,6.05\n" + 
        "2015-02-20,6.05\n" + 
        "2015-02-19,6.09\n" + 
        "2015-02-18,5.90\n" + 
        "2015-02-17,5.98\n" + 
        "2015-02-16,6.00\n" + 
        "2015-02-13,6.20\n" + 
        "2015-02-12,5.54\n" + 
        "2015-02-11,5.25\n" + 
        "2015-02-10,5.64\n" + 
        "2015-02-09,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-02-06,5.15\n" + 
        "2015-02-05,5.27\n" + 
        "2015-02-04,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-02-03,5.69\n" + 
        "2015-02-02,5.12\n" + 
        "2015-01-30,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-01-29,4.78\n" + 
        "2015-01-28,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-01-27,5.17\n" + 
        "2015-01-26,5.82\n" + 
        "2015-01-23,5.63\n" + 
        "2015-01-22,5.16\n" + 
        "2015-01-21,4.94\n" + 
        "2015-01-20,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-01-19,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-01-16,4.77\n" + 
        "2015-01-15,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-01-14,5.03\n" + 
        "2015-01-13,5.31\n" + 
        "2015-01-12,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-01-09,4.93\n" + 
        "2015-01-08,4.76\n" + 
        "2015-01-07,4.97\n" + 
        "2015-01-06,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-01-05,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-01-02,5.55\n" + 
        "2015-01-01,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-10-28,10";  
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get your data from somewhere
    var data = csvData();

    // Set highlight start and end
    var highlight_start = new Date('2015/01/01');
    var highlight_end = new Date('2015/10/28');

    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
        data,
        {
            animatedZooms: true,
            underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {
                var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(highlight_start,0);
                var top_right = g.toDomCoords(highlight_end,2500); 
                console.log(bottom_left);               
                console.log(top_right);

                var left = bottom_left[0];
                var right = top_right[0];

                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

[[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/0amokpwm/4/) If you want to see it running. Basically what I did was copy the `underlayCallback` function from the example you referred too. I then adapted it to work with dates.

This was accomplished by...

```
var highlight_start = new Date('2015/01/01');
var highlight_end = new Date('2015/10/28');
```

I then feed those into the `underlayCallback` to be used to determine the coordinates for the `canvas.fillRect` function.

As I mentioned before these data ranges are larger than you data set. Regardless all you need to do is adjust those Data string in that format style to get the desired results.

Comment: one additional question: how can i add annotations? -> adding: g.setAnnotations([
    {
      series: "Temperature",
      x: "2008-05-08",
      shortText: "L",
      text: "Coldest Day"
    }
    ]); doesn't work.. ?!

Comment: @MartinGöpfert I would open up a new StackOverflow Q/A as this is a completely new question.